# UserNotification with UNCalendarTrigger not working

Tags: swift, notifications

I'm trying to implement Local Notifications for iOS, they will be triggered in a weekday, hour and minute the user indicates, but I can getting to work, the notification simply doesn't appear at that hour and minute in that particular weekday. I'm able to get them to work with a UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "It's time for " + (habit.name ?? "do a habit")
        content.body = "Completing yours habits is food for soul."
        
        content.sound = .default
        
        for day in weekdays.days {
            let components = DateComponents(hour: Int(habit.remindHour), minute: Int(habit.remindMinute), weekday: day)
            print("Registering a notification with trigger", components)
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "\(habit.objectID)", content: content, trigger: trigger)
            notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    debugError(.notifications, "Couldn't schedule a notification", error: error)
                }
            }
        }
```

**Adding the notifications doesn't throw an error**, and the `print` function, does return a valid date component object:

```
Registering a notification with trigger hour: 14 minute: 15 weekday: 3 isLeapMonth: false
```

The `days` array goes from `2...6`, hence the weekdays

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, I was replacing sending them with the exact same id, so concatenate the id with the weekday number.